# Using AVRCP with two devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, avrcp

I want to use AVRCP features for music control, and according to https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth/services Android is supporting that. But as I get through docs there is no API for using it. Is it possible to establish such a connection between two Android devices?